# what is difference between spring-ws,CXF,soap(camel component) to call web service?

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

i am new to camel?
i am not able to distinguish between camel web-service component
so please help me to find out difference between those component
and also suggest that in which situation which component is better to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camel SOAP is not a component but a data format http://camel.apache.org/soap.html it's used for marshaling and unmarshaling SOAP payloads.

Spring-WS http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html uses Spring Web Services to provide client and server side SOAP support.

Camel-CXF http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html uses Apache CXF to provide client and server side SOAP support.

Camel-CXF is my goto tool when I have to deal with SOAP. It's a mature and very full featured component (and underlying library). The only time I use Spring-WS is if I'm dealing with very outdated SOAP that is using RPC encoding which CXF doesn't support.

Comment: Thanks Tracy Snell
That Helps me a lot